# Photon Voice - Combine Recorder and Audio Source (Karaoke App)

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, voice, photon

I'm developing a karaoke application but I'm having difficulty getting the audio from the mic and the audio from the music to sync on clients.

My solution right now is using Photon Voice to end the mic (as normal) and the music is being transferred the same way but uses a Factory and IAudioPusher - Unfortunately the audio isn't in sync, I guess I was optimistic in thinking it would be!

I'm looking for advice on how I can achieve this, maybe if there's a way to combine AudioSource's in real time? If not, if anyone has any other suggestions then they'd be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is way out of my league but is the delay in voice always the same? In that way you should try to implement some kind of "lag compensation" the same way competitive FPS do where you calculate client side where the other character is based on latency.